# get string from text file and divide into array

Tags: php, arrays, file, preg-split, file-read

I wants to divide the string from text file.

if the .txt file has been read from some location. i wants to read the file and get strings in array.

Text file have following data

```
aaa  1111111,
    2hajakka,
    87uj5687,
     F2tryty   
bbb  45454545,
    rereer,
    87uj5687,
     4343343,
    944dsdds
```

I wants to store lines in array like

```
$arr = array(
"aaa 1111111, 2hajakka, 87uj5687, F2tryty ",
"bbb 45454545, rereer, 87uj5687, 4343343, 944dsdds");
```

notes:
data have starts first line as name, like(aaa,bbb) data's separated by commas. if comma not in the line it goes to next array field

Thanks in advance

Comment: your asking like 1-1 = 2 ( your expecting )!! how!!!!! its pos.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$file_handle = fopen("myfile.txt", "r");
$arr[] = "";
$i = 0;
$temp_string = '';

while (!feof($file_handle)) {
$line = fgets($file_handle);
if(strpos($line,",")!== false)
{
$temp_string = $temp_string.$line;}
else{
$temp_string = $temp_string.$line;  
$arr[$i] = $temp_string;
$temp_string = '';
$i++;}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

what you're trying to do is quite simple:

1. collapse the multi-line records into a single line
2. split the lines into an array

pretty much:

```
<?php
$string = 'aaa  1111111,
    2hajakka,
    87uj5687,
     F2tryty   
bbb  45454545,
    rereer,
    87uj5687,
     4343343,
    944dsdds';

// move lines beginning with a space to the previous line
$string = preg_replace('#\n +#', ' ', $string);
// split lines into array
$array = explode("\n", $string);
var_dump($array);
```

Comment: thank u rodney but i have another doubt if i give empty spaces in data's like "1111 111, 2ha ja kka, 87 uj5 687, F 2try ty" how i use preg_replace

Comment: how exactly do these spaces behave?

Comment: like this rodney, J1.A1 DUT.A1  DUT.A2 C1.1 C2.1 , F2.1 F4.1 K1.1 , F2.1 F4.1 K1.1 , F2.1 F4.1 K1.1

Comment: urm, what? I have no clue what the meaning of `944dsdds` is, I don't know if the space preceeding ` 4343343` has any relevance and if so, what it means. Nor do I know why `rereer` is one character shorter than the other keys (without a preceeding or trailing space). If all that has any meaning, please elaborate. Otherwise it just looks like badly formatted text.